# Is it possible to override the texture component values even though the variable is set to public?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I have a texture issue with a VR whiteboard. When I attach a texture to a plane in Unity that has the whiteboard.cs script attached, the whiteboard plane defaults to plain white when I press run. The plane is still reactive to the marker in a VR space, but I want to be able to put up a stencil texture/material that allows users to trace it. I've seen the similar issue when the variables are private and not when set to public. Has anyone experienced the same texture GetComponent issue? I'm using Unity 2021.2,10f.

Attached is a screenshot of the object before and after pressing run and the mentioned script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Whiteboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 textureSize = new Vector2(x:2048, y:2048);

    void Start()
    {
        var r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        texture = new Texture2D(width:(int)textureSize.x, 
        height:(int)textureSize.y);
        r.material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the question ... what exactly is not working as expected? Or what exactly are you asking? In general `Is it possible to change something that is pulic` -> I'd say that's one o the main reasons why to make things public ... if it can be changed depends on whether it is a read-only property or not I guess ...

Comment: Btw your screenshots are missing and  why don't you simply use a [`Vector2Int`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html) ;)

Comment: Ah man, so sorry, late night... edited to add the images of the object with the attached script and material pre and post pressing run in Unity. Will be sure to try the Vector2Int now.